# wrong and not understandable dependency added by stack solver

Tags: stackage

I have a large and complex package which does compile on two computers but not on the third one (the files are moved by zip and scp). The error message is

```
In the dependencies for leksah-0.17.0.0:
    process-1.4.2.0 from stack configuration does not match >=1.4.3.0 && <1.7
                    (latest matching version is 1.6.4.0)
needed since leksah is a build target.
```

I cannot find where the process-1.4.2.0 comes from. It is not in the resolver lts 9.9 (the resolver gives process-1.4.3.0   Process libraries), nor in the cabal file for leksah. Where else should I look? (I have exact-match in the config).

the stack.yaml from global-project is

```
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
packages: []
extra-deps: []
resolver: lts-10.4
```

the config.yaml contains (besides the templates) only `compiler-check: match-exact`.

the project stack.yaml is

```
resolver: lts-9.9
packages:
- '.'
- 'vendor/leksah-server'
- 'vendor/ltk'
- 'vendor/haskellVCSGUI/vcsgui'
#- 'vendor/yi'
- 'vendor/haskellVCSWrapper/vcswrapper'

# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps:
- binary-shared-0.8.3
- haddock-api-2.17.4
- haskell-gi-overloading-0.0
- gi-gtk-hs-0.3.5.0
- gi-gtksource-3.0.15
- gi-javascriptcore-4.0.14
- gi-soup-2.4.14
- gi-webkit2-4.0.14
- gi-gdk-3.0.14
- gi-gdkpixbuf-2.0.14
- gi-glib-2.0.14
- gi-gobject-2.0.14
- gi-gtk-3.0.17
- gi-cairo-1.0.14
- gi-gio-2.0.14
- gi-pango-1.0.15
- gi-atk-2.0.14
- gi-gtkosxapplication-2.0.14

# Override default flag values for local packages and extra-deps
flags:
  gi-atk:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-cairo:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gdk:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gdkpixbuf:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gio:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-glib:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gobject:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gtk:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gtk-hs:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gtksource:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-javascriptcore:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-pango:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-soup:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-webkit2:
    enable-overloading: false
  gi-gtkosxapplication:
    enable-overloading: false

# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs: []
```

the cabal files contain (the first is the relevant one for the project, the others are in the packages) - none of them is asking for process-1.4.2.0

```
   process >=1.4.3.0 && <1.7,
    process >= 1.0.1.1,
    process >=1.0.1.5 && <1.7,
    process >=1.0.1.5 && <1.7,
    process >=1.0.1.5 && <1.7,
    process >=1.0.1.5 && <1.7,
    process >=1.0.1.5 && <1.7,
    process >=1.1 && <1.7,
    process >=1.1 && <1.7,
    process >=1.1 && <1.7,
    process >=1.1 && <1.7,
```

adding process-1.4.3.0 to the extra deps resolves the requirements - but WHY IS THIS NECESSARY? it is in lts 9.9! - It does, as expected, not compile - there must be other packages not selected the same than on the other computer.

Comment: Can you include the relevant `stack.yaml` (either from your project or from `~/.stack/global-project/`)?

Comment: I edited the question to include all information I think could be helpful. It remains a mystery to me! Thank you for help!

Comment: Strange indeed. I think you should report this on `stack`'s issue tracker.

Comment: I did report it on the stack issue tracker -#4281. hope for an answer!